# What do the Python VSCode syntax colors mean?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

VSCode has syntax highlighting for the Python language. I can't find any explanation for how each token is classified and organized into colors.

Specifically, why are some keywords the same color, but some are different?

Looking at this code:

[image: Code example in VSCode]

`for...in` shows the keywords as the same color, but `if...in` shows the keywords as different colors. Why does `in` change color? What determines if a keyword is purple or blue or something else?

Finally, is there an exhaustive list or chart for how keywords are organized?

Comment: `for...in` and `if...in` are python keywords

Comment: @Trevin Avery  Have you got the answer you need?

Comment: @JillCheng Yes, I just found it and updated the question with the exact answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the code in VSCode is provided by the theme. (VSCode uses its own theme by default.) Reference: [syntax-highlighting-optimizations](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) and [theme color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

Using different themes can make the code display different colors. You could also set the color of custom code. Reference: [Customizing a Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes).

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same `in`. The first is used to iterate while the second is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

From the first link in @JillCheng's answer I found the [Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector), which can be enabled by running `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the command palette. This will then show how the currently selected text was tokenized.

`for...in` shows both keywords are tokenized as `keyword.control.flow.python`.

`if...in` shows `if` as `keyword.control.flow.python` and `in` as `keyword.operator.logical.python`.

---

*<sub>Note: This answer was originally posted as part of the question.</sub>*